# $C_0(M)^*$ where $C_0(M)$ is the space of functions vanishing at infinity can be identified with the set of regular Radon measures.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $M$ be a locally compact Hausdorﬀ space. A continuous real valued function $f \colon M \to \mathbb R$ is said to vanish at inﬁnity if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact set $K \subset M$ such that $$\sup_{x\in M-K} |f(x)| < \epsilon$$ Denote by $C_0(M)$ the space of all continuous functions $f \colon M \to \mathbb R$ that vanish at inﬁnity (see Exercise 3.2.10).

(a) Prove that $C_0(M)$ is a Banach space with the supremum norm.

*no problem here*

''(b)The dual space $C_0(M)^∗$ can be identiﬁed with the space $\mathcal{M}(M)$ of signed Radon measures on M with the norm (1.1.4) [They refer to the total variation to be the norm], by the Riesz Representation Theorem (see [75, Thm. 3.15 & Ex. 3.35]). Here a signed Radon measure on $M$ is a signed Borel measure μ with the property that, for each Borel set $B \subset M$ and each $\epsilon$ >0, there exists a compact set $K \subset B$ such that |$\mu(A)−\mu(A \cap K)| <\epsilon$ for every Borel set $A \subset B$.''

*What exactly am I being asked to do here, other than quote the result of Riesz? I'm very confused here.  What exactly does it mean to prove spaces ''can be identified'' with another?*

(c) Prove that the map $\delta \colon M \to C_0(M)^∗$, which assigns to each $x \in M$ the bounded linear functional $\delta_x \colon C_0(M) \to \mathbb R$ given by $\delta_x(f) := f(x)$ for $f \in C_0(M)$, is a homeomorphism onto its image $\delta(M) \subset C_0({M})^∗$, equipped with the weak$^*$ topology. Under the identiﬁcation in (b) this image is contained in the set $P(M) := \{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(M): 
\mu \ge 0, \|\mu\| = \mu(M) = 1\}$ of Radon probability measures. Determine the weak$^*$ closure of the set $\delta(M) = \{ \delta_x | x \in M \} \subset$ $P(M)$.

Comment: The Riesz Representation theorem usually refers only to positive linear functionals. I guess the question is to extend this to a statement about all bounded linear functionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part (b) is not really meant as a question, just as information that you will need to solve part (c).  However, you might take it as an opportunity to solve Exercise 5.35 (not 3.35, it's a typo) of the book [75], which is *Measure and Integration* by Dietmar A. Salamon.  Note that the statement at hand is *not* exactly what is shown by [75] Theorem 3.15, which is only about *positive* measures and positive linear functionals.

Formally, "can be identified with" would be to say that there is an isometric isomorphism between these two normed spaces: a bijective linear map $T : \mathcal{M}(M) \to C_0(M)^*$ which is an isometry (i.e. $\|T\mu\|_{C_0(M)^*} = \|\mu\|_{TV}$).  The map should be understood to be $(T\mu)(f) = \int f\,d\mu$.  Proving that this map is a bijection and an isometry are parts (iii) and (i) of [75] Exercise 5.35.  So once this has been shown, you can think of the measure $\mu$ and the functional $T\mu$ as "the same object", and whenever you are asked to prove something about a measure, you could instead prove the corresponding fact about the corresponding functional, or vice versa.

In particular, the sentence "under the identification in (b)" in part (c) should be understood as saying that $T^{-1}(\delta(M)) \subset P(M)$.

Comment: I think the traditional Reiz Rep. Thrm is only on compactly supported functions (identified with Borel measures), so I have to extend this notion to functions vanishing at infinity and identify them with Radon measures? I suspect I have to use Hahn-Banach extension in some way but cannot parse the details.

Comment: @Muselive: I think for this proof, you only need the easy converse of that: every linear functional on $C_0(M)$ is automatically a linear functional on $C_c(M)$.  But what you said is also true: in general, if $X$ is a Banach space and $Y \subset X$ is a dense subspace, then the restriction map from $X^*$ to $Y^*$ is a bijection (and an isometry).  In particular, every continuous linear functional on $Y$ extends to a unique continuous linear functional on $X$.  You don't need Hahn-Banach to prove this.

Comment: I'm confused. I have, via Reiz, that all elements of $C_C^*$ have the form: $T_\mu(f)=\int f d\mu$ I want this extend the map $T_\mu(f)$ to a  functional on $C_0$.  If not Hahn Banach, do I make some kind of compactification argument? That is, add the point $\infty$ to $M$ then use Reiz? This feels complicated.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what statement you mean when you say "Reiz" (btw the correct spelli g is "Riesz")?  Theorem 3.15 of [75] only characterizes **positive** elements of $C_c^*$.

Comment: I am suggesting you go the other way around.  Suppose you have an element of $C_0^*$.  It is **already** an element of $C_c^*$.  Therefore, by the argument you seem to know, it is therefore of the form $\int f\,d\mu$.

Comment: @Muselive: Or at least, we have $\Lambda(f) = \int f\,d\mu$ for all $f \in C_c$.  But every $f \in C_0$ is a uniform limit of a sequence $f_n \in C_c$.  Pass to the limit, using the continuity of $\Lambda$ on the left and the triangle inequality on the right.

Comment: If I'm reading the most recent comment correctly, $\bar{C_c}$ (closure taken wrt uniform norm) =$C_0$? should this be obvious?

Comment: @Muselive: Yes, that's right. In many books this is the definition of $C_0$.  Otherwise it's a good exercise using cutoff functions (which you can produce via Urysohn's lemma).

Comment: Could I ask you to write the argument ''Pass through the limit...use the triangle inequality on the right'' precisely?

Comment: @Muselive: Since $\Lambda$ is a continuous linear functional on $C_0$, in which the norm is the uniform norm, we have $\Lambda(f_n) \to \Lambda(f)$.  Next, the triangle inequality tells us that $\left| \int f_n \,d\mu - \int f\,d\mu \right| \le \int |f_n - f| \,d|\mu| \le \|f_n-f\|_{\sup} |\mu(M)|$.  Since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, this goes to 0, telling us that $\int f_n\,d\mu \to \int f\,d\mu$.  And since $\Lambda(f_n) = \int f_n\,d\mu$ for all $n$, we conclude that $\Lambda(f) = \int f\,d\mu$.

Comment: Any hints for c)? I think the measures in $delta(M)$ are point measures a la;$ \int f d\mu_x=f(x)=\delta_x f$ so $I_{\mu_x}(f)=\delta_x f$ but I can't seem to write anything else. My book has several theorems regarding the image of canonical imbedding of vector spaces, but they're unusable as M is merely a LCH space..